# Use italic font for selected text in textxy()

Tags: r

I am using calibrate library to place text in an xy plot and would like to change font for certain parts of the text.  In the example below, I would like for `'K'` to have italic font and the rest of the text in normal font.

```
textxy(7.5, 6, 'Arrows indicate optimal K', cx=0.8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a plotmath expression and to make use of the `italic()` plotmath function, e.g.:

```
textxy(7.5, 6, expression("Arrows indicate optimal" ~ italic(K)), cx=0.8)
```

or

```
textxy(7.5, 6, expression(Arrows~ indicate ~ optimal ~ italic(K)), cx=0.8)
```

Here is a full example:

```
require("calibrate")
plot(1:10, type = "n")
textxy(5, 5, expression("Arrows indicate optimal" ~ italic(K)), cx=0.8)
```

[image]

Comment: Gavin: It seems like this answer pushed you to 50K from 49.9K.  Awesome!

Comment: @cryptic0 Not quite - the amount you see is rounded. Currently at 49976, but thanks all the same :-)